# @media screen (min-width:1200px) not working in Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have a problem in `@media screen (min-width:1200px)`.

I have set 2 kinds of attributes (classes) for an image and the  in the CSS, expecting it to make the image and the "td" in which I put the image smaller when resizing the screen, but when the screen is more than 1200px still it shows the smaller size of the image.

This is the HTML :

```
 <tr>
     <td class="indexphototd">
         <img class="indexphoto" src="../wp-content/uploads/2013/05/indexphoto300.jpg" /></td>
     <td>more stuff here</td> 
 </tr>
```

This is the CSS :

```
/* for browsers larger than 1200px width */
@media screen (min-width: 1200px) {
     .indexphototd { 
            width:300px !important;
        }
     .indexphoto {
         width:300px !important;
      }
}


@media screen (min-width: 800px) {
     .indexphototd {
            width:200px !important;
        }
     .indexphoto {
         width:200px !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: It's a good idea to avoid using `!important` unless absolutely necessary.

Comment: Could you show us example on jsFiddle? I will try help You then.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your media queries overlap:  1200px is still 800px or larger.  Simply reverse your media queries.

```
@media screen (min-width: 800px) {
     .indexphototd {
            width:200px !important;
        }
     .indexphoto {
         width:200px !important;
      }
}

@media screen (min-width: 1200px) {
     .indexphototd { 
            width:300px !important;
        }
     .indexphoto {
         width:300px !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot cimmanon. It works. Its a magic. Really appreciated. I am new to web development. Learning all these magical things. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Isaac If this post solved your problem, I would suggest marking it as the answer by clicking on the checkmark to the left of it. This lets others who have the same problem benefit from your question if they see it.

Answer (score 1):

If a screen is say 1400px in width then the 800px will also take effect in your current setup. Swap them around like so:

```
@media screen (min-width: 800px) {
     .indexphototd {
            width:200px !important;
        }
     .indexphoto {
         width:200px !important;
      }
}
@media screen (min-width: 1200px) {
     .indexphototd { 
            width:300px !important;
        }
     .indexphoto {
         width:300px !important;
      }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot - its working. But I have another problem now. When I shrink the screen to less than 1200 px it stays at 300 and not moving to 200 though. Its happening in all 3 browsers - IE, FF & Chrome. I have even removed the !important.

Comment: Ensure that this CSS is BELOW all other CSS otherwise it will get overidden by your non responsive default values

Comment: I though this answer helped??