# Two @media variables, issue

Tags: css, media-queries

I have two @media variables in my css thats cause a problem.

One is with smaller width `@media only screen and (min-width: 1290px)`.
And the second one is with greater width `@media only screen and (min-width: 1610px)`, allowing me to display more content.

Now, with my browser window in full screen, and a monitor resolution of 1680 x 1050 pixels, I still cannot get `@media only screen and (min-width: 1610px)` to appear.

Am I missing something?

Thanks.

Comment: If the CSS file with `(min-width: 1290px)` is inactive, the CSS file with the greater width, takes over. But if both are active, It goes back to `(min-width: 1290px)`.

Comment: If your viewport is 1680px wide, *both* media queries apply (`1680 >= 1290` *and* `1680 >= 1610`).  What order do the media queries appear?

Comment: @cimmanon I am linking the files, they go _<link href="five.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">_
_<link href="four.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">_. **five.css** being `(min-width: 1610px)` and **four.css** being `(min-width: 1290px)`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [@media screen (min-width:1200px) not working in Chrome](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16549413/media-screen-min-width1200px-not-working-in-chrome)

Comment: That worked. Thanks. I just had to reorganize the css files in the <head> section. BTW @cimmanon You didn't post in the answer section, so I can mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try setting the max-width also for your first condition, as currently both your "min-widths" will be hit when the resolution is > 1610px.

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 1609px) and (min-width: 1290px){
}
```

Comment: That did not work. If both are set to max-width, it doesn't even read the css.

Comment: Only set "max-width" on the first condition, the second one can be left with just "min-width:1610px"

Comment: That combination doesn't work as well. It does display the `(min-width: 1610px)`. But when you shrink the browser, it does not read the CSS for `(max-width: 1290px)`.

Comment: it does not read the CSS for (max-width: 1290px) - It should be min-width:1290px!

Comment: That is the first thing I tried, `(max-width: 1610px)` and `(min-width: 1290px)`. It does not display the adjustments  for `(max-width: 1610px)`.